# unexpected result(-wS-wx--T) on file permission with open() function in C

Tags: c, linux, unix

I wrote this program to open a file. Everything was OK until I saw this permission(-wS-wx--T) with `ls -lh`

**open.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE "foo.txt"

int main()
{
        int fd;
        int errnum;

        fd = open(FILE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);

        if(fd == -1)
        {
                printf("[error] The file hasn't opened.\n");
                perror("Error printed by perror");
        }else {
                printf("The process was succeeded\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I compiled the program featly, didn't take any error or warning.

```
$ ./open
The process was succeeded
$ ls -lh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 hemre hemre 8.5K Feb  1 23:38 open
--wS-wx--T 1 hemre hemre    0 Feb  1 23:39 foo.txt
```

I haven't ever seen kind of permission. What are 'S' and 'T' meaning in
the file permissions section? 
(NOTE: I took the answer to this question in the comments.)

Comment: If you're looking for explanations on Linux filesystem permissions, it may be better to look on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AntonH this permission came after a C program. I think it is related here too.

Comment: @jxh umask is 0002.

Comment: @jxh # file: open_1.txt
# owner: arien
# group: arien
# flags: -s-
user::rw-
group::-wx
other::---

Comment: open() allows a third argument: the intended mode for if the file needs to be created. -->> `fd = open(FILE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);`

Comment: BTW: `#define FILE` is asking for trouble. stdio defines FILE (a bad name, agreed)  please use another macroname, like `#define FILENAME "omg.txt"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you include `O_CREAT` in the flags passed to `open()` then you ***must*** use the three-arg form of the function, which takes a numeric file mode as the third argument.  This requirement is documented in [the Linux manual page for the function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) (emphasis added):

> The `mode` argument specifies the file mode bits be applied when   a
>   new file is created.  **This argument must be supplied when   `O_CREAT` or
>   `O_TMPFILE` is specified in `flags`**; if neither `O_CREAT`   nor `O_TMPFILE` is
>   specified, then mode is ignored.

What mode you actually want is unclear, but perhaps `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP` would be suitable (== `0640`; read and write for the owner, read only for the owner's group, no permission for anyone else).

Comment: What's that mean S and T?

Comment: @H.Emre, the 'S' in the `ls` output represents the file's SUID bit.  The 'T' represents the sticky bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found two different definition of open function, you can see them with `man 2 open` and `man 3 open` in linux terminal.

`man 2 open` for Linux Programmer's Manuel.
`man 3 open` for POSIX Programmer's Manuel.

If you use **POSIX Programmer's Manuel** definition(sample code in the question) for open function, you can take unexpected permissions(like -wS-wx--T).
If you use **Linux Programmer's Manuel** definition(sample code below) you can take regular permission.
I am not sure that's true but I noticed it. 
If I am faulty please correct me.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

            int fd;

            if(argc != 2){
                    printf("[usage] %s <file_name>\n", argv[0]);
                    exit(0);
            }

            fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH);
        if(fd == -1){
                perror("[error] open function\n");
                exit(-1);
        }else{
                printf("[succeeded]\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```